# PIL Image not rendering inputted pixel values in correct order

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library, render

Just for fun I thought I'd try to build an image with pixel values then render it with `PIL.Image`.

But it's not rendering the values I'm inputting.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# custom array
arr = np.array(
    [[50,200,50],
     [50,200,50],
     [50,200,50]])

print(arr)

img = Image.fromarray(arr, 'L')
img.show()
```

`[[ 50 200  50]  [ 50 200  50]  [ 50 200  50]]`

The outputted image is below.

[image]

Given high pixel values are white and low pixel values are dark, I would have expected a white line down the middle of the image.

What went wrong here?

Comment: That's not the result I get when I execute your code — it's what I would expect.

Comment: Your array is `int64` in type which is not supported by PIL. Try adding `dtype=np.uint8` where you create it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell happy to accept your answer if you want to post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Mark Setchall for your comment.

Adding `type=np.uint8` when creating the array solved it for me.

```
arr = np.array(
    [[50,200,50],
     [50,200,50],
     [50,200,50]], type=np.uint8)
```

Now I get what I expected.

[image]

Comment: Well done for writing it up. I knew the answer but didn't have time to test it and write it up so I just left a comment to get you started :-)